# How to extend a class with static methods?

Tags: node.js, static, typescript

I want to extend my `UserModel.model` object with static functions. How can I do it?

As you can see below, my `UserModel.model` is a mongoose model object, but I need to add methods to this object, the point is: I don't know how to write it. I can't use a `static{}` area like in Java/C# to execute static code, I don't find the way to write it. Do you?

For instance, I want to add methods such as `exists`, `connect`, etc.

```
///<reference path='../../lib/def/defLoader.d.ts'/>

import model = require('./Model');

export module Models {
    export class UserModel extends model.Models.Model implements model.Models.IModel{
        /**
         * Name of the model.
         * MUST start by uppercase letter!
         */
        private static modelName: string = 'User';

        /**
         * Public readable schema as object.
         */
        public static schema: any = {
            /**
             * User Login
             */
            login: {
                type: 'string',
                minLength: 4,
                maxLength: 16,
                required: true,
                notEmpty: true,
                unique: true
            }
        };

        /**
         * Private schema as mongoose.Schema type.
         */
        private static _schema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema(UserModel.schema);

        /**
         * The mongoose model that uses the mongoose schema.
         */
        public static model: mongoose.Model<any> = mongoose.model(UserModel.modelName, UserModel._schema);



        /**
         *************************************************************************************************
         *********************************** Public (Helpers) ********************************************
         *************************************************************************************************
         */

        /**
         * Name of the model.
         * MUST start by uppercase letter!
         */
        public modelName: string;

        /**
         * Contains the static value of the public schema as object.
         * It's a helper to always get the schema, from instance or static.
         */
        public schema: mongoose.Schema;

        /**
         * Contains the static value of the object used to manipulate an instance of the model.
         * It's a helper to always get the model, from instance or static.
         */
        public model: mongoose.Model<any>;

        /**
         * Use static values as instance values.
         */
        constructor(){
            super();

            // Use static values as instance values.
            this.modelName = UserModel.modelName;
            this.schema = UserModel.schema;
            this.model = UserModel.model;
        }

        /**
         *************************************************************************************************
         *********************************** Extended methods ********************************************
         *************************************************************************************************
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a simple example of what you're trying to achieve at http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/?

Comment: Too complicated because of many references. I tried anyway. Edit main post.

Comment: Stackoverflow refuses the link ... Too long, even for other app like Tiny Link.

Comment: What I want to do is add methods: UserModel.model.exists = function(){}

Comment: Why not add statics to the Models the way MongooseJS intended it to be  done?

Comment: I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, I'm just looking for a solution, I'll try yours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you just use the standard MongooseJS way of adding a static method to a Model by using the `statics` property of a `Schema` instance as shown below.

```
module MongooseDemo {
    export class Demo {
        public static LoginSchema: any = {
            /* User Login */
            login: {
                type: 'string',
                minLength: 4,
                maxLength: 16,
                required: true,
                notEmpty: true,
                unique: true
            }
        };      

        public static Model : any; // static store for data 

        constructor() {
            // there is not a concept of a static constructor in  
            // typescript, so static initialization code may be better else
            // where
        }       
    }

    // I've made this an anonymous function that is private to the module
    // It's executed immediately and initializes the "static" values of the 
    // class. this code could be moved into a static method of course and 
    // and called directly in the same way
    (()=> {
        // create the schema defined
        var schema : any = mongoose.Schema(Demo.LoginSchema);
        // add the statics before creating the model
        // http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics
        schema.statics.exists = () => {
           // here's a static method                    
        };
        // create the model
        Demo.Model = mongoose.Model('Demo', schema);

    })();
}
```

As there isn't a concept of a static constructor in JavaScript or Typescript, I've created an anonymous function inside of the `MongooseDemo` module to automatically initialize the static fields of the class. You could of course move the code around, but the general concept should work.

Or, you could just add the static methods directly to the model after it is created (again, in the anonymous method):

```
Demo.Model.exists2 = () => {
    // something different              
};
```

The actual code for adding a class method/static in Mongoose is very simple as it simply copies all functions (and properties) from the `statics` property of the `Schema` object instance to the new `Model` directly. So, the second example I've provided is functionally equivalent to the first way I proposed that is [documented](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics).

Comment: That does works, thank you. My problem was more with TypeScript way to write it, I tried to use the "function" keyword instead of the "()". Pretty new with TS :)

Comment: I tried both ways, the best is the second because of the debugging, if you made some kind of error, everything will be red, depending on the IDE. (WebStorm 7.0.3), it's better to use the second way and have each methods not in the same block.